# execute a child process using nodejs

Tags: node.js

Am trying to up an emulater using nodejs
using comamnd line iam using like this

```
C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion>player --vm-name "Samsung Galaxy Note 2 - 4.3 - API 18 - 720x1280"
```

i want o perfrom this in `nodejs`
my code

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile,
    child;

var getVms = function () {

    var device = 'Samsung Galaxy Note 2'
    var version ='4.3'    
    //command = process.env.GENY
       command = "C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion"
    command += "\\player"
    command += " --vm-name"
    command += " \"" + device + " - " + version + " - API 18 - 720x1280"+"\"";
console.log(command)
        var child = exec(command);
        child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('stdout:---------------------- ' + data);
        });
        child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('stdout err:---------------------- ' + data);
        });
        child.on('close', function(code) {
            console.log('closing code:---------------------------- ' + code);
        });
}
getVms();
```

but am getting the output

```
closing code:---------------------------- -1
```

with out up the emulator.whats wrong with my code

Comment: Have you read docs?
http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback

Comment: yes...i tried all ways but nothing getting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to execute a file, you can also try `spawn`. And you should be aware that arguments are passed as arrays. Try this out:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

exports.getVms = function (req, res) {
    process.chdir("C:\\Program Files\\Genymobile\\Genymotion");
    var execCmd = './player';
    var args = ["--vm-name", " \"" + device + " - " + version + " - API 18 - 720x1280"+"\""];
    var spw = spawn(execCmd, args);

    spw.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        var str = data.toString()
        res.send(str);
    });

    spw.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('ps stderr: ' + data);
        res.send(500);
    });

    spw.on('close', function (code) {
        console.log('process exit code ' + code);
    });
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU MAN..YOUR GR888..WORKING NOWWWWWWW